# ListView.Builder => ListTile => Highlighted Tile... ERROR

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want the Sellected tile to be Highlighted... I tried wraping every single widget in Expnded and Flexible didnt worked..**

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#6612d relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
package:flutter/…/rendering/box.dart:1
Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.

These invalid constraints were provided to RenderParagraph's layout() function by the following function, which probably computed the invalid constraints in question:
_RenderListTile._layoutBox

The offending constraints were: BoxConstraints(w=Infinity, 0.0<=h<=34.0)
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListTile
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: _RenderListTile#e6266 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
RenderObject: _RenderListTile#e6266 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
    parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
    constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=34.0)
    size: MISSING
    title: RenderParagraph#0aab5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
        parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0)
        constraints: MISSING
        size: MISSING
        textAlign: start
        textDirection: ltr
        softWrap: wrapping at box width
        overflow: clip
        textScaleFactor: 1.1
        locale: en_US
        maxLines: unlimited
        text: TextSpan
            debugLabel: (((englishLike titleMedium 2014).merge(blackMountainView titleMedium)).copyWith).merge(unknown)
            inherit: false
            color: Color(0xffffffff)
            family: eng
            size: 25.0
            weight: 700
            baseline: alphabetic
            decoration: TextDecoration.none
            "1990"
```

```
class AddToyota extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddToyota({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddToyota> createState() => _AddToyotaState();
}

class _AddToyotaState extends State<AddToyota> {
  // Initial Selected Value
  String currentYear = '2022';

  // List of items in our dropdown menu
  var itemss = [
    '1990',
    '1991',
    '1992',
    '1993',
    '1994',
    '1995',
    '1996',
    '1997',
    '1998',
    '1999',
    '2000',
  ];
  int? selectedIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue.shade900,
        title:
            Image.asset("assets/toyota.png", color: Colors.white, height: 45),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 50,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: itemss.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          itemss[index],
                          style: const TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: 'eng',
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        tileColor: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.amber : null,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
child: Column(
         //STRETCH TO FIT WIDTH
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          
          children: [
            //REMOVED CONTAINER FROM HERE
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: itemss.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctxt, int index) {
                    return Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      //CHANGED TO CARD
                      child: Card(
                        Color: selectedIndex == index ? Colors.amber : null,
                        onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedIndex = index;
                          });
                        },
                       child : Container(
                                 height: 50,
                                 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.blue.shade900,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                ),
                              //PUT CHILD OF ANYTHING HERE
                               child : 
                                )
                        ),
                        
                        
                      
                    )
                  }),
            
          ],
        )
```